# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

here is the code listing and i got the above mentiond error at line `nests(r,c)=nests(r,c)+stepsize.*randn(size(nests(r,c)));` please let me now what is wrong with my code as i m new to matlab

```
    for r = 1:numb_of_nest % for each particle

      for c = 1:4
         u=randn(size(nests(r,c)))*sigma;
         v=randn(size(nests(r,c)));
         step=u./abs(v).^(1/beta);
         nests(r,c)=nests(r,c)+stepsize.*randn(size(nests(r,c)));

        % Apply simple bounds/limits
        ns_tmp=nests(r,c);
        I=ns_tmp<Lb(c);
        ns_tmp(I)=Lb(I);

        % Apply the upper bounds 
        J=ns_tmp>Ub(c);
        ns_tmp(J)=Ub(J);
        % Update this new move 
        nests(r,c)=ns_tmp;

         end
     end
```

Comment: If you're looping through both dimensions, you don't need the sizes, you're only ever handling scalars. You can also omit the `.` in pretty much all of those operators since you're not even dealing with matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you assign a value of some dimension `m x n` to a subscripted variable of different dimension.

In your case, assuming `nests` has no third dimension, you're assigning to a scalar (`1x1`) variable. This only works if the value you're trying to assign also is a scalar. Since you get the error, it probably isn't. The only place where your dimensions can be non-scalar is `stepsize`, so to fix this error, **make sure `stepsize` is a scalar value**.

According to the definition you gave in an earlier comment (`stepsize=0.01*step.*(nests(r,c)-best);`), this problem translates to **make sure `best` is a scalar value**. Possibly by subscripting, I can't tell you exactly how since I don't know what `best` is.

Comment: best is the scalar value which denote best nest in the previous solution thnx @scenia i was doing same mistake by refering best as vector

Answer (score 0):

```
     step=u./abs(v).^(1/beta);
     nests(r,c)=nests(r,c)+stepsize.*randn(size(nests(r,c)));
```

Here you're assigning a value to the variable **step**, but then using a different variable called **stepsize** that hasn't been assigned a value anywhere in this code. Is this intentional? If not, stepsize is probably some leftover variable from previous code which is messing up the dimensions and giving you this error.

In addition to the above, is `nests` an ordinary two-dimensional matrix in your code? If so, taking `size(nests(r,c))` every time is unnecessary - since you're giving two subscripts, the result is only going to be `1` all the time. Or is `nests` a cell array perhaps? In that case, you might want to index using curly braces `{` `}` instead of ordinary parantheses, to get the size of the matrix that's sitting inside the cell.

Comment: sorry i missed the line in code where step is used to calculate stepsize  which is 'stepsize=0.01*step.*(nests(r,c)-best);'and nests is vector with four parameters of gabor which varies according to number of gabor filter in gabor filter bank

Comment: @Amir what's `best` in that case?